# Temporary grayed out text in textbox

Tags: java, swing, text, textbox

I would like to show a text like "write your message here." that automatically disappears after the textbox gets the focus?
I was trying to do this without having to deal with listeners, with an initial text for example.

Comment: What you're looking for is "placeholder text" and I don't think the Swing components support it out-of-the-box.

Answer (score 1):

Try the example. I think that's what you need
http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/11/29/text-prompt/

Answer (score 1):

SwingX contains a class "PromptSupport" that does exactly what you need.
It's very easy to handle:

```
JTextField tf = new JTextField(5);

PromptSupport.setPrompt("A Prompt", tf);
```

Take a look here:
http://weblogs.java.net/blog/kschaefe/archive/2010/07/15/swingx-using-promptsupport

You can download the jar-file here:
http://java.net/downloads/swingx/releases/